# VLA in C++ with std=c++11 extension

Tags: c++, gcc

How is VLA working in C++ despite giving `-std=c++11` compile option. As per GCC:

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int fun()
{
    int j;
    cin>>j;
    return j;
}

int main()
{
    const int i=fun();

    int j[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably need `-pedantic` as well as `-std=c++11` (or even `-pedantic-errors`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, It has now given a warning with `-pedantic` option!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) mentions in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807703/vla-in-c-with-std-c11-extension?noredirect=1#comment111068477_62807703), [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) has the `pedantic` option that also  disallows extensions:

> `-Wpedantic`
>
> `-pedantic`
>
> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other
> programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++. For ISO C, follows the
> version of the ISO C standard specified by any `-std` option used.
>
> Valid ISO C and ISO C++ programs should compile properly with or without this option (though a rare few require `-ansi` or a `-std` option
> specifying the required version of ISO C). However, without this
> option, certain GNU extensions and traditional C and C++ features are
> supported as well. With this option, they are rejected.
>
> `-Wpedantic` does not cause warning messages for use of the alternate keywords whose names begin and end with ‘`__`’. This alternate
> format can also be used to disable warnings for non-ISO ‘`__intN`’
> types, i.e. ‘`__intN__`’. Pedantic warnings are also disabled in the
> expression that follows `__extension__`. However, only system header
> files should use these escape routes; application programs should
> avoid them. See Alternate Keywords.
>
> **Some users try to use `-Wpedantic` to check programs for strict ISO C conformance. They soon find that it does not do quite what they
> want: it finds some non-ISO practices, but not all—only those for
> which ISO C requires a diagnostic, and some others for which
> diagnostics have been added.**
>
> A feature to report any failure to conform to ISO C might be useful in some instances, but would require considerable additional
> work and would be quite different from `-Wpedantic`. We don’t have plans
> to support such a feature in the near future.
>
> Where the standard specified with `-std` represents a GNU extended dialect of C, such as ‘`gnu90`’ or ‘`gnu99`’, there is a corresponding
> base standard, the version of ISO C on which the GNU extended dialect
> is based. Warnings from `-Wpedantic` are given where they are required
> by the base standard. (It does not make sense for such warnings to be
> given only for features not in the specified GNU C dialect, since by
> definition the GNU dialects of C include all features the compiler
> supports with the given option, and there would be nothing to warn
> about.)
>
> `-pedantic-errors`
>
> Give an error whenever the base standard (see `-Wpedantic`) requires a diagnostic, in some cases where there is undefined behavior at
> compile-time and in some other cases that do not prevent compilation
> of programs that are valid according to the standard. This is not
> equivalent to `-Werror=pedantic`, since there are errors enabled by this
> option and not enabled by the latter and vice versa.

The emboldened part is my emphasis — apparently some things may still slip by. Still, I find this option enough for my needs.